# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x-y}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is what i did:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}& =\frac{x^2-xy-y^2}{x-y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}& =\frac{(x+y)(x-y)-xy}{x-y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}& =x+y-\frac{xy}{x-y}
\end{align}
I put $z=\frac{y}{x-y}$, is this solution alright?
I could not just go on, because the equation is neither Bernoulli or exact or homogenous.

Comment: Do you believe it has a closed-form solution and why?

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: `Maple` or `Mathematica` can't solve.